# Making tkinter notebook tabs shrink to fit or adding scrolling to tabs

Tags: python, tkinter, tabs, tk-toolkit

How can I add scrolling to the tabs of the tkinter notebook? By default notebooks will just expand when more tabs are added but that can lead to errors for apps where the user can add them. I understand there are answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51105771/scrolling-notebook-tabs-tkinter) but when tested they showed errors I couldn't fix on my own. I personally liked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59803188/17053202) best (The look and feel of it) but found many errors that despite days of going through I couldn't fix. If this not possible how would I instead add shrinking of tabs? I have heard people say that it automatically shrinks but when I try to do this it doesn't shrink for me. Any ideas? Can you just limit the size the notebook can take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a frame. Put it in a frame and turn pack_propogate to false for the frame