# Tkinter - Scrolling notebook tabs without expanding the window width

Tags: python, tkinter, text, tabs

I'm trying to make a tkinter window with tabs, and a text widget for each tabs. I ended up using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59803188/12349101) as basis. Started with this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

tab_count = 1

def create_tab():
    global tab_count
    tab = ttk.Frame(notebook)
    notebook.add(tab, text=f"<Untitled> {tab_count}")
    text_widget = tk.Text(tab)
    text_widget.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    notebook.select(tab)
    text_widget.focus_set()
    tab_count += 1  # Increment the tab_count

def switch_tab(event=None):
    current_tab = notebook.select()
    notebook.select(current_tab)
    current_tab_widget = notebook.nametowidget(current_tab)
    text_widget = current_tab_widget.winfo_children()[0]
    text_widget.focus_set()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Text Editor")

frame = ttk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

notebook = ttk.Notebook(frame)
notebook.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

create_tab()  # Create the initial tab

add_button = ttk.Button(frame, text="New Tab", command=create_tab)
add_button.pack(side="bottom")

notebook.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", switch_tab)

root.mainloop()
```

to this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import NE, LEFT, RIGHT

class ScrollableNotebook(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.xLocation = 0
        self.notebookContent = ttk.Notebook(self, **kwargs)
        self.notebookContent.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.notebookTab = ttk.Notebook(self, **kwargs)
        self.notebookTab.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", self._tabChanger)

        slideFrame = ttk.Frame(self)
        slideFrame.place(relx=1.0, x=0, y=1, anchor=NE)
        leftArrow = ttk.Label(slideFrame, text="\u25c0")
        leftArrow.bind("<1>", self._leftSlide)
        leftArrow.pack(side=LEFT)
        rightArrow = ttk.Label(slideFrame, text=" \u25b6")
        rightArrow.bind("<1>", self._rightSlide)
        rightArrow.pack(side=RIGHT)
        self.notebookContent.bind("<Configure>", self._resetSlide)

    def _tabChanger(self, event):
        self.notebookContent.select(self.notebookTab.index("current"))

    def _rightSlide(self, event):
        if self.notebookTab.winfo_width() > self.notebookContent.winfo_width() - 30:
            if (self.notebookContent.winfo_width() - (self.notebookTab.winfo_width() + self.notebookTab.winfo_x())) <= 35:
                self.xLocation -= 20
                self.notebookTab.place(x=self.xLocation, y=0)

    def _leftSlide(self, event):
        if not self.notebookTab.winfo_x() == 0:
            self.xLocation += 20
            self.notebookTab.place(x=self.xLocation, y=0)

    def _resetSlide(self, event):
        self.notebookTab.place(x=0, y=0)
        self.xLocation = 0

    def add(self, frame, **kwargs):
        if len(self.notebookTab.winfo_children()) != 0:
            self.notebookContent.add(frame, text="", state="hidden")
        else:
            self.notebookContent.add(frame, text="")
        self.notebookTab.add(ttk.Frame(self.notebookTab), **kwargs)

    def forget(self, tab_id):
        self.notebookContent.forget(tab_id)
        self.notebookTab.forget(tab_id)

    def hide(self, tab_id):
        self.notebookContent.hide(tab_id)
        self.notebookTab.hide(tab_id)

    def identify(self, x, y):
        return self.notebookTab.identify(x, y)

    def index(self, tab_id):
        return self.notebookTab.index(tab_id)

    def insert(self, pos, frame, **kwargs):
        self.notebookContent.insert(pos, frame, **kwargs)
        self.notebookTab.insert(pos, frame, **kwargs)

    def select(self, tab_id):
        self.notebookContent.select(tab_id)
        self.notebookTab.select(tab_id)

    def tab(self, tab_id, option=None, **kwargs):
        return self.notebookTab.tab(tab_id, option=None, **kwargs)

    def tabs(self):
        return self.notebookContent.tabs()

    def enable_traversal(self):
        self.notebookContent.enable_traversal()
        self.notebookTab.enable_traversal()

tab_count = 1

def create_tab():
    global tab_count
    tab = ttk.Frame(notebook.notebookContent)
    notebook.add(tab, text=f"<Untitled> {tab_count}")
    text_widget = tk.Text(tab)
    text_widget.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    notebook.notebookContent.select(tab)
    text_widget.focus_set()
    tab_count += 1
def switch_tab(event=None):
    current_tab = notebook.notebookContent.select()
    current_tab_widget = notebook.notebookContent.nametowidget(current_tab)
    if current_tab_widget.winfo_children():  # Check if there are any children widgets
        text_widget = current_tab_widget.winfo_children()[0]
        text_widget.focus_set()




root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Text Editor")

frame = ttk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

notebook = ScrollableNotebook(frame)
notebook.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

create_tab()

add_button = ttk.Button(frame, text="New Tab", command=create_tab)
add_button.pack(side="bottom")

notebook.notebookContent.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", switch_tab)
root.mainloop()
```

Now this works at first glance, but I noticed whenever tabs get added, and they exceed the window's width, they end up increasing the current width of the window (unless it is maximized/fullscreen)

How do I prevent the window's width from increasing when windowed and adding tabs?

Comment: `self.pack_propagate(0)`

Comment: where do I put this? in `__init__`? @Thingamabobs

Comment: Yes, that will stop your window from growing, since the geometrical properties won't be propagated anymore and growing slaves of the frame have no impact of the frames size and therefore on the window.

Comment: I tried to add it at the end of `__init__` but it created a small window the same size as a tab. @Thingamabobs

Comment: `self.configure(height=500, width=500)` will solve that.